# Google Colab上でGoogle Spread Sheetの指定のページを読み込みたい

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, google-colaboratory

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Google Colab上でGoogle Spread Sheetの指定のページを読み込みたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

URLの末尾に"gid=" で指定しても、一番左側のページしか読み込まない
該当のソースコードで指定したURLは"gid=57719256"。これは「罹患者関係」というタブのページのもの。

しかし、以下のページはスプレッドシートの一番左側のタブの「はじめに」というページが表示されている。

```
0    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><scrip...
1                                         はじめにお読みください。
2    本データセットの構築プロジェクトは、株式会社SIGNATE（https://signate....
3    プロジェクトに参加される方は、「COVID-19チャレンジ（https://signate....
4                            趣意やタスクの内容を理解した上で、ご参加ください。
..                                                 ...
344  (function(){var a=_.wd();if(_.C(a,18))Jj();els...
345                     }catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}
346                                    })(this.gbar_);
347                                     // Google Inc.
348  </script><script nonce="QCXx6uXK7nhk+YWIYJMCBA...
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```py
!wget --no-check-certificate --output-document=data.csv "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CnQOf6eN18Kw5Q6ScE_9tFoyddk4FBwFZqZpt_tMOm4/edit#gid=57719256"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=None, sep='\n')
print(df)
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

・使用しているGoogle Spread Sheet ：[SIGNATE COVID-2019 Dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CnQOf6eN18Kw5Q6ScE_9tFoyddk4FBwFZqZpt_tMOm4/edit#gid=642719404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ちゃんと調べていませんが、wget だと JavaScript が実行されておらずシートが変わらないのかもしれません。

プログラムから spreadsheet にアクセスするには、Google Sheets API を使うのが一般的です。

- API の説明：https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts?hl=ja
- Python での使い方の説明：https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?hl=ja

Comment: ありがとうございます。返信遅くなりました。
色々と調べまして「gspred」というPythonでスプレッドシートを操作することができるライブラリを使用しました。

Answer (score 2):

自己回答です。

nekketsuuuさんの回答を元に解決した方法を記しておきます。

## 1. gspreadをインストール

```
!pip install gspread
```

## 2. 各種パッケージをimport

```
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import gspread
```

## 3. 認証処理

```
# 認証処理
auth.authenticate_user()
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
```

## 4.スプレッドシートを開く

```
workbook = gc.open_by_url(スプレッドシートのURL)
```

## 5.該当タブにアクセス

```
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(タブの名前)
```

以上の流れで取得したいワークシートにアクセスできました

---

【参考にしたサイト】

- [Google ColaboratoryでGoogleスプレッドシートを読み書きしてみる - uepon日々の備忘録](https://uepon.hatenadiary.com/entry/2018/04/08/110916)
- [gspreadライブラリの使い方まとめ！Pythonでスプレッドシートを操作する | たぬハック](https://tanuhack.com/library-gspread/)
- [【Python】スプレッドシートを操作するライブラリ「gspread」の使い方まとめ｜Fresopiya](https://fresopiya.com/2019/04/19/gspread/)